# Custom Tooltip on Image item of Datalist Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip, qtip2

I have a datalist control in my usercontrol and I have icon image "detail.png" . now I want to show some customised tooltip (like this [qTip_Tooltip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax) ) on the click event of that image.
the thing is the tooltip content should come from database.

I have 2 tables that comes in the picture.. 1. StudentMaster . 2. StudentCategoryMaster.
before using tooltip, I had a seprate page where we can see the details of the perticular student, explained below..
 When we have to see the detail of the perticular student, i have to pass 2 parameters, Viz. studentId & studentCategoryId.
like this

aspx code

`<a href='<%# FormatStudentId((int)Eval("studentId"), (int)Eval("studentCategoryId")) %>'>`

.cs code

```
protected string FormatStudentId(int studentId, int studentCategoryId)
{
    return "StudentDetails.aspx?studentId=" + studentId.ToString() + "&studentCategoryId=" + studentCategoryId.ToString();
}
```

So, when we have to show the tooltiup, the tooltip must have been passed with these 2 ID's. So the dynamic tooltip scenario will come into the picture.

My question is, How to achieve this ?
Please help me.
Thank You for reading , I guess I was clear enuf, if not, ask me the detail, i will give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, `<AjaxControlToolkit:HoverMenuExtender>` and edit the `<div>` in the `<asp:Panel>` as the way you want.

Like this..

```
<asp:Panel ID's ...>
<div style="">
<%#Eval("studentDescription")%>
<br />
</div>
```

Google for this extender, you will find so many nice examples.

Comment: +1 and marked as answer, as I dint find any relevant solution other than yours. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

details.png will contain tooltip for a particular student? You can follow the same way your example does and Fill the p tag dynamically

Comment: Thanks dear for replying. but i want customized tool tip and not the one which comes by default, as it is not at all customizable. I want just like http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax this